# Linked List Partition Node Value Changing in Python

Tags: python, linked-list

I was attempting to solve the question for Linked List Partitioning in CTCI book, and I'm not sure I fully comprehend the behavior here when I looked at the python solution from [here](https://github.com/w-hat/ctci-solutions/blob/master/ch-02-linked-lists/04-partition.py).

```
def partition(head, pivot):
   a_head, a_tail = None, None
   b_head, b_tail = None, None
   node = head
   while node:
       if node.data < pivot:
           if a_head:
               a_tail.next, a_tail = node, node
           else:
               a_head, a_tail = node, node
       else:
           if b_head:
               b_tail.next, b_tail = node, node
           else:
               b_head, b_tail = node, node
       node = node.next
   a_tail.next = b_head
   return a_head

 class Node():
     def __init__(self, data, next=None):
         self.data, self.next = data, next

     def __str__(self):
         string = str(self.data)
         if self.next:
             string += ',' + str(self.next)
         return string

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_partition(self):
        head1 = 
         Node(7,Node(2,Node(9,Node(1,Node(6,Node(3,Node(8)))))))
        head2 = partition(head1, 6)
        self.assertEqual(str(head2), "2,1,3,7,9,6,8")
        head3 = partition(head2, 7)
        self.assertEqual(str(head3), "2,1,3,6,7,9,8")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

Why do we `return a_head` at the end if it's only assigned `node` value at the first hit of `else` statement when its value is `None`? I printed out the value of `a_head` throughout the process and it seems to change value when `a_tail.next = head`.

I don't understand why that happens. I assumed setting `a_tail.next = head` only applies to `a_tail`, so not sure why it changes `a_head` value as well.

Comment: The line `a_head, a_tail = node, node` is the only one that assigns a value to `a_head`.  We're returning a mutated version of the linked list, and `a_head` is the head of that list. I think it should be mentioned that for poorly chosen `pivot` values, this function may raise an exception trying to do `None.next`.

Comment: I can see how the mutation happens in terms of `a_tail`, I just don't understand why `a_head` mutates as well. Having a hard time wrapping my head around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
a_head, a_tail = node, node
```

`a_head` and `a_tail` are both references to the same object.  So later, when you do

```
a_tail.next, a_tail = node, node
```

for the first time, that sets `a_head.next` as well, since at this point in time `a_head` and `a_tail` are the same object.

Comment: Oh, I assumed they both have separate copies of the object! I didn't think that both would be referencing the same object after the assignment. Thank you for clarifying this!

Comment: This is a pretty good article on the subject of what names and assignment actually do in python: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html